# How to request only particular fields from an XML output?

Tags: php, xml, api, curl

I have an access key to an API, which allows me to obtain data about products (such as price, description, etc).

I am aware of 2 manual ways to use this key:

1) Use the "modify headers" firefox addon, insert the key in the headers, and then type the URL that will yield an XML file (`https://api.domain.com/search?parameter=something`),
and I will see an output tree like this:

```
<manufacturer-name>SONY</manufacturer-name>  
<price>99.99</price>
```

Along with another 20 fields.

2) Use PHP file with this code:

```
$myHeaders = array("key: code");

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/search?parameter=something");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$myHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$returnResult = curl_exec($ch);

if ($returnResult) {
    //parse HTTP Body to determine result of request
    if (stripos($returnResult,"Error Code ")) {
        // error occurred
        trigger_error($returnResult,E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else{
        // success
        echo $returnResult;
    }
}

else{
    // connection error
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch),E_USER_ERROR);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

And then I see this output:

`SONY 99.99`

My question:

Using same PHP code, how can I request only the `price` field to show up?

(I ask this because later on, I will want my server to make auto requests like this, and update my own database with the current values of these fields).

Answer (score 1):

This is what `SimpleXML` is for: load an xml file and parse it.

```
<?php
$myHeaders = array("key: code");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.domain.com/search?parameter=something");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$myHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$returnResult = curl_exec($ch);

// here the dom is generated
$xml = simplexml_load_string($returnResult);
print_r($xml);
// depending on your root element and xml tree:
// echo $xml->...->price->__toString();
?>
```

For a better answer, show us the precise xml output (including namespaces, etc.).

Comment: In order to obtain access to the API, I need to use particular headers with my key, so I probably must curl, right? so what would be the exact line I should add? `echo simplexml_load_string(price)`?

Comment: See my updated answer and show the `print_r()` output in your question (simply edit it).

Comment: thanks, but what's `_toString()`? I Get a fatal error if i keep it. if i delete it I do get the value.

Comment: @rockyraw Sorry, it should have read `__toString()` (two underscores, my fault). Converts the SimpleXML Element to a string.

Comment: @rockyraw Converting the element to a string.